# How to export jenkins job data to splunk in json format

Tags: json, groovy, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I need to export jenkins data like build num , build status, build duration etc to splunk in json format. The format will be like this.
{
Buildnum : 'build_num',
BuildStatus : 'build_status',
BuildEndTime : buildendtime
}

How can i get these variable in jenkinsfile in social coding. Do i have to write groovyscript and then do something in jenkinsfile? I have hec url for the splunk server also.
I am totally new to this topic and stuck here. Please anyone help me in this.